# SQL the query returns only 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql

the query returns only 1 result, please help

```
select 
p.products_id, pd.products_name
from
products_description pd, 
products_to_categories p2c,
products p
where 
EXISTS (SELECT p2pef.products_id 
                  FROM products_to_products_extra_fields p2pef
                  WHERE p2pef.products_extra_fields_id = '78' 
                 and p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'tak' 
                   and p.products_id = p2pef.products_id )
and 
EXISTS (SELECT p2pef.products_id 
                  FROM products_to_products_extra_fields p2pef
                  WHERE p2pef.products_extra_fields_id = '94' 
                  and p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'tak'
                    and p.products_id = p2pef.products_id )          


and p.products_status = '1'
and p.products_id = pd.products_id
and p.products_id = p2c.products_id
and pd.language_id = '4'
and p2c.categories_id = '26'
group by p.products_id
```

What do you think about this query using EXISTS?

You may have another idea to display products from the products table that meet several conditions with additional fields from the products_to_products_extra_fields table.

table schema:

products (4 rows)

```
 _________________________
 products_id
 _________________________

 1
 2
 3
 4
```

products_to_products_extra_fields ( 8 rows)

```
 ___________________________________________________________________
 products_id products_extra_fields_id products_extra_fields_value
 ___________________________________________________________________
 1 94 tak

 1 78 tak

 2 94 tak

 2 78 tak

 3 94 tak

 3 78 tak

 4 94 nie

 4 78 tak
```

a valid query should return (3 rows)

```
 _______________
 products_id
 _______________

 1

 2

 3
```

Comment: the `EXISTS` part seems to be ok. the problem is probably that your other filters select just one `product_id`

Comment: Indeed, do all *product_ids* return without `EXISTS` clauses?

Comment: Hi. What does "meet several conditions" mean? You seem to be interested in inputting some representation of "conditions" and outputting a query, but you don't explain in enough detail that we could know what a correct answer is. Please also read & act on [mcve]. Indeed, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Please let us know what expected behavior is?

Comment: what's the status of the question? you've been given answers and nowhere did you comment under them to tell them if it worked or not, yet alone accepted an answer in order to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `having` clause to achieve this as well:

```
select      p.products_id
from        products p
inner join  products_description pd
         on p.products_id = pd.products_id
inner join  products_to_categories p2c
         on p.products_id = p2c.products_id
inner join  products_to_products_extra_fields p2pef
         on p.products_id = p2pef.products_id
where       p.products_status = '1'
and         pd.language_id = '4'
and         p2c.categories_id = '26'
and         p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'tak'
and         p2pef.products_extra_fields_id in ('78', '94')
group by    p.products_id
having      count(distinct p2pef.products_extra_fields_id) = 2
```

.. but the result will be the same. If you have fewer records than expected, make sure all the products you expect to be in the output also fulfil the other conditions on status, language and category.

NB: use the `join` syntax for expression join conditions.

Comment: I believe that it is not completely equivalent for any data. If he is interested in `product_id`s having extra field rows (78, 'tak'), (94, 'nie'), then you approach might be difficult to extend to work corectly.

Comment: Indeed, for other conditions, another `having` condition would have to be written. For instance: `count(unique case when p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'tak' and products_extra_fields_id = '78' then 1 when p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'nie' and products_extra_fields_id = '94' then 2 end)`